# Mysql join in rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two tables orientations and registrations that I would like to perform a join query on. Here is the schema for each of the tables...

```
create_table "orientations", :force => true do |t|
    t.date     "class_date"
    t.text     "class_time"
    t.integer  "seats"
    t.boolean  "active",     :default => true
    t.datetime "created_at",                   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   :null => false
  end

 create_table "registrations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "orientation_id"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "student_id"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "registration_cancellation_token"
    t.datetime "registration_cancelled_at"
    t.boolean  "checked_in",                      :default => false
    t.boolean  "cancelled",                       :default => false
    t.datetime "created_at",                                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                         :null => false
    t.text     "program"
  end
```

What I am looking for is all registrations for all orientations between two dates. I came up with this...

```
Registration.where(Orientation.where created_at: => @start_date..@end_date)
```

Of course that syntax is bogus, but hopfully it will help get across what I am looking for.

Comment: Registration.includes([:orientation]).where("orientation.created_at between ? and ?", @start_date, @end_date) ...try with this and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get all registrations for all orientations between two dates:

```
Registration.joins(:orientation).where(orientations: {:class_date => @start_date..@end_date})
```

`joins` performs an *INNER JOIN* which filters the rows that don't have association.

But, if you wish to keep the rows that don't have associations then go for `includes` which performs a *LEFT OUTER JOIN*

```
Registration.includes(:orientation).where(orientations: {:class_date => @start_date..@end_date})
```

Comment: Thanks Kirti, but these all return no results. FYI some of the registrations have nil orientation_id's. Would this cause the query to return no results?

Comment: Interesting. If I use the 2nd query (includes) and I use a puts to view the results in the console I get an empty array returned. Here is the console output: http://pastie.org/9287293. However if I go to my mysql DB and execute 'SELECT `orientations`.* FROM `orientations` WHERE (`orientations`.`class_date` BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-07');' then it returns valid results.

Comment: @Lumbee Registrations with `nil` orientation_id's will not be part of results in the first query as it performs INNER JOIN. But second query should cover those due to LEFT OUTER JOIN. Also, you want the condition on `class_date` column or `created_at` column? As in the question you mentioned `created_at` and in the above comment you are using `class_date`? in mysql

Comment: Hey @Kirti, you are correct! I needed to search based on :class_date. Once I did that, the queries worked. You rock! Thanx!

Comment: Glad to help. :) I will update my answer to reflect `:class_date` attribute.